# Ruby variables referencing other variables

Tags: ruby, variables, object, reference

I have two variables, one (`b`) that references the other (`a`).  When I modify `a` with a method, `b` is also modified:

```
a = "TEXT"
b = a
print b
#=> TEXT   
a.downcase!
print b
#=> text
```

However, when I modify `a` directly, `b` retains its value:

```
a = "TEXT"
b = a
print b
#=> TEXT
a = "Something Else"
print b
#=> TEXT
```

Why is the behavior of `b` different when the variable it initially referenced is modified directly as opposed to by a method?

Is this an improper thing to do in Ruby, and if so, what would a better practice be for referencing one variable with another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the object_id to see what is going on here.

```
a = "text"
a.object_id
 => 70200807828580

b = a
b.object_id
 => 70200807828580  # b points to the same object that a does.

a = "new"
a.object_id
 => 70200807766420  # a now points to a new object

b.object_id
 => 70200807828580  # b still points to the original object.
```

So you see that the variable actually doesn't store the object itself.  Instead it stores the id of the object.  That's why if you copy an object you usually just copy the id of it rather than creating a whole new object.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby works with references, and you are making a little mistake in there.

This:

```
a.downcase!
```

as the 'bang' method suggests, is changing the value referenced by `a`.
So `a` is still the referencing the same object, which was just changed by the downcase! method

But this:

```
a = "Something Else"
```

is actually saying to `a` to reference a new object which happens to also be a string.
Since `b` was referencing another object and that object didn't changed, it still prints TEXT.